# How to pre-process data with tensorflow's tf.data.Dataset API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm currently using tensorflow's tf.data.Dataset API to read in & feed my dataset to the model for training (built using `Dataset.from_generator(...)`).

However, I'm unsure of how to pre-process the dataset for features that require an entire pass through the dataset. For example, to compute word vocabularies for embedding features, an entire pass through the dataset would be required, so I can't really use `tf.data.Dataset's map()` function here.

I looked into `tf.transform's` APIs (with Apache beam), but it seems like I can't input a `tf.data.Dataset` object into a pipeline, only a list in memory or as files from disk.